# Css UL UL problem on IE8 and FF 4 - Disc appears on 2nd line in the vertical menu

Tags: css

Site is www.uppercanadawebdesign.com/test If you click on "New Equipment" to expand the menu, I get the disc image showing on a second line. It works ok in Chrome, but not in IE8/FF4.
I think it has something to do with the css around line 960 ".sidebar .box ul ul". If I remove the "disc" from the list-style, the problem is resolved, but then I don't get the little disc showing on the sub-menu items.

(Note: this is a Wordpress Site)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Add to #dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul, #dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul li the following:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That does resolve the problem of the disc appearing on a second line. Is there a way to keep the 'disc' (bullet) in front of the 2nd level menu items, on the same line as the text?

Comment: You can by adding padding-left to the 2nd level, but this would not be a clickable area. I agree with wanting some indication that is the second level. I recommend making a bullet image and placing it with background-image... Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by adding (as you suggested): `list-style-type: none;` to the  #dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul, #dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul li .
 I then added the following to the

```
#dc_jqaccordion_widget-3-item ul ul a {:  
   background-image: url(http://uppercanadawebdesign.com/test/wp-content/uploads/bullet2.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 3em;
    background-position: 20px 50%;
```

It now works in FF4, IE8 and Chrome....